# Store default sequence number in table without using any variable

Tags: sql-server

I have one table in database which should contain sequence number.

```
create table SequenceNumber(
number int indentity(1,1) primary key
)
```

Now I want to store number from 1 to 1448 without setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF and without counter variable.

I need values from 1 to 1448 in 'number' column

can anyone tell me how can I do it?

Comment: "without setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF" - why such an arbitrary restriction?

Comment: @MitchWheat because I some one told me that you can insert default value in identity column with out setting it on/off. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it as follow 
just change the value 1448 as per your need

idea from here : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780441/Tricky-SQL-Questions

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceNumber(
NUMBER BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
)


WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SequenceNumber
    DEFAULT VALUES

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SequenceNumber WHERE NUMBER = 1448) 
        BREAK
END

SELECT NUMBER FROM SequenceNumber
```